# Джанго - импорт товаров с картинками из excel-файла

Tags: django, excel, изображения, импорт

Пример, есть модель:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    code = models.PositiveIntegerField('Код товара')
    price = models.DecimalField('Цена товара', max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

как импортировать данные из ексель файла и создавать товары я понял. Не могу понять, как осуществить импорт картинок к товару через ексель. Перелопатил весь интернет, не смог найти. Возможно ли это?